# Android : check when listview finish implementation or ready

Tags: android, android-listview, android-lifecycle, android-handler

**PROBLEM**

I want to click Listview Programmatically after onResume() and retain ListView but I don't know when and where should I implement click logic because now it Force close because I call function to early (I have check return view is null)

I use Handler() Runnable() and Thread() method becuase I think that this will queue my code after listview finish implementation.

What should I do??

**EXAMPLE OF USING HANDLER RUNNABLE and THREAD**

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            DataManager dm = new DataManager(getActivity());
                            for (int i = 0; i < scheduleLvItems.size(); i++) {
                                if (dm.readPF(String.valueOf(i)).equals("open")) {
                                    System.out.println("RESTATE -----------------> " + i);
                                    if(isAdded())
                                        System.out.println("TOGGLE POSITION ----> "+ i);
                                        toggle(i, false, 0);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();
```

**LOGCAT**

```
6-10 15:19:24.349      314-314/com.bis.org.auInsight E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.bis.org.auInsight.ScreenSlidePageFragment.toggleAnimation(ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:517)
            at com.bis.org.auInsight.ScreenSlidePageFragment.toggle(ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:487)
            at com.bis.org.auInsight.ScreenSlidePageFragment.access$100(ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:24)
            at com.bis.org.auInsight.ScreenSlidePageFragment$1$1.run(ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:117)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**On line 517**

```
listItem.getWrapper().startAnimation(resizeAnimation);
```

**DEBUG CODE**

```
System.out.println("DEBUG GET WRAPPER -> "+schedule_listView.getWrapper());
```

**DEBUG RESULT**

```
06-10 15:19:24.329      314-314/com.bis.org.auInsight I/System.out﹕ DEBUG GET WRAPPER -> null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear. Please edit it to state exactly what you're asking and provide all details concisely.

The exception you're receiving is caused by the fact that `getWrapper()` returns `null`. What is this function? Did you implement it yourself? Try to debug inside and see why it's `null`.

Also, I see no point in wrapping a `Runnable` in another `Runnable`. Why not post the inner `Runnable` directly?

Maybe the code in the separate thread doesn't run before you call `getWrapper()` and that's why it returns `null`?

Comment: Getwrapper is to getview of the select item in listview but it return null because maybe the runnable is excute too soon before listview finish implement itself so my question is how can I know that when listview finish their implementation so when I getwrapper it won't be null

Comment: What do you mean by 'implement'? And why don't you `post` this code after you're sure this 'implementation' is finished?